# How to change the compiler in Qt creator 64-bit

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I created a application in linux and now I am trying to import this application to windows which is 64-bit. I installed Qt creator(64-bit) and imported the project.I am using certain libraries like omniORB4 which are built on 64-bit.Now when I try to build the application I get the following error:

```
module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
```

Qt Version : Qt 5.3.1 (MSVC 2013, 64 bit)

Visual Studio :2010

When I imported the project in Qt on windows there was a option to configure the project and it showed only " Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10.0(x86)" in the options. I think I am getting this error because my compiler is x86. there are few other compilers which are shown in Project Properties but when I select them it gives me a error. Is there any way that I can change my compiler to x64 in QT and what are the other options that I can follow to resolve this issue. I looked into many links but still no luck.

Comment: Remember to install the 64-bit version of Qt as well, otherwise Qt Creator will most likely complain it can't use the 64-bit compiler.

Comment: @rubenvb I have 64-bit Qt installed on my machine. When I check the version it shows "QT 5.3.2 (MSVC 2013, 64 bit). I have only Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 installed on mine. Do I need 2013 for it to work.

Comment: well, yes, the C++ ABI breaks between releases, you can't mix them. Make sure you have a "kit" for your x64 compiler and Qt version, and it should pick them when you add a project build configuration.

Comment: @rubenvb I installed Visual Studio professional 2013 and it still does not give me that option.

Comment: what option, where? There's three things you need: a Qt version, a compiler, and a kit. These options appear in three different tabs of the Tools->Options->Build & Run settings page. First the compiler, then the Qt version, then the kit combining the two. Add any or all of the three manually if you must.

Comment: (i) See [Adding Compilers](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html) to tell Qt Creator where to find your compiler.
(ii) See [Adding Qt Versions](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html) to tell Qt Creator where to find the Qt binaries.
(iii) Finally, see [Adding Kits](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html) to tell Qt Creator how to combine your compiler with the Qt binaries.